# MBeanExporter and conditional loading of a bean

Tags: java, spring, jmx, mbeans

I want to use MBeanExporter to expose a Mbean. However, it is not necessary that the bean to be exported is always present. How should this be handled :

```
<bean id="mybean" class="org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter" lazy-init="false">
    <property name="beans">
        <map>

            <entry key="bean:name=DatabaseDataSource" value="#{datasource.getPool().getJmxPool()}"/>

        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

It might be that getJmxPool() returns null sometimes when the export fails. How can this be made conditional(no mbeans exposed) if it is known that a particular property when set will cause this to return null.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at spring environment profiles:

http://gordondickens.com/wordpress/2012/06/12/spring-3-1-environment-profiles/

If a particular environment or configuration flag should not instantiate the bean, just tag the bean with a particular profile using `@Profile`. Spring will not try to instantiate the bean if it doesn't match the active profile.

Comment: Is it possible to use a property loaded through propertyplaceholderconfigurer to decide the profile activation

Comment: you can set the active profile programmatically with `getEnvironment().addActiveProfile("profile")`. You can then either make that the name of a profile or conditionally set a profile of your choice

Comment: can profile activation be done after propertyplaceholderconfigurer has loaded properties?

Comment: yes, it can be done using the method i mentioned above.